# DIfference in structs?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

What's the difference between:

```
typedef struct part 
{
   int a;
} Part;
```

and

```
typedef struct 
{
   int a;
} Part;
```

I know the second one is "anonymous" but are they different?

Comment: In the second case, you won't be able to refer to the type as `struct part`. The difference is significant while you are making a self-referencing (list or tree) data structure where `struct part *child` must be a member of the struct.

Comment: @SylvainDefresne It's also valid C++ code and OP didn't say they're only interested in C.

Comment: Potential usage for self-referencing aside, there's no runtime difference between these two structs.  If that was the main gist of your question.

Comment: They have different names, same difference as `struct A { }` and `struct B { }`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In addition to Mike Seymour answer, here's an example of why:

Linked list for example

```
// this works
typedef struct part {
    struct part *next;
} Part;

// this doesn't work
typedef struct {
    struct Part *next;
} Part;
// neither this
typedef struct {
    Part *next;
} Part;
```

Comment: Why? What's the point of making that restriction? Why aren't you allowed to do the second thing?

Comment: How could the compiler know what is Part (in the second example) when it's not defined yet ?

Comment: But then how can the compiler know what `struct part *next` is when its definition hasn't been completed yet?

Comment: It can't for the second example because Part is a typedef, so this type need to be defined (typedef is the name). In the first case, the compiler know that its a struct and its enough to continue

Comment: @dfg The compiler doesn't need to know about the definition of the class, as long as it knows it's there. It's like forward declaring something.

Comment: @dfg You don't need a complete type definition for a pointer or reference.  You only need to know the type exists.

Comment: How does the compiler know how much memory to allocate for the struct, if it just knows its type?

Comment: If the memory allocation is on "hold" then why does it need to know the type?

Comment: I completed my answer. Look at the last example, it's how a beginner should try to do at first try. You can see that Part is used before it is declared, so it's something unknown and trigger and error

Comment: @dfg, when you declare the field `struct part *next;` you're declaring a pointer, so the compiler knows that it needs to allocate space for a pointer-type.

Comment: @dfg The memory allocation is **not** on hold.  You can only declare a pointer or reference there as a pointer/reference will always have a known size.  If you tried to declare a member, it will fail because the size is not known (requires complete definition)

Comment: But then why does't the second structure in the answer work? The compiler doesn't need to know what Part is since its only making a pointer right?

Comment: @dfg It still needs to know the type exists for type safety, you just don't need to know its size.  You can't say `myTypeThatDoesntExist * foo` anywhere in your code either.

Answer (score 15):

In both cases you define a structure type, and a type alias called `Part` which refers to that type.

In the first case, you also define a structure name `part`, so the structure type can also be referred to as `struct part`, or just `part` in C++.

In the second case, the structure itself has no name (hence "anonymous"), and can only be referred to by the type alias. Since that alias is only declared *after* the structure definition, the structure cannot refer to itself.

Comment: But why would you care how you can refer to it as long as you *can* refer to it?

Comment: @dfg: You can only refer to it within the structure definition (before the declaration of `Part`) by the structure name - and only if it has one.

Comment: Why? What's the point of making that restriction? Why aren't you allowed to self reference it?

Comment: @dfg: In general, you can only use names after they've been declared. The point of that restriction is to allow the program to be parsed in a single pass, making compilation much quicker than it otherwise would be.

Answer (score 1):

And in addition to @EoiFirst 's answer,

```
typedef struct part 
{
   int a;
   struct part *next;
} Part;
```

This is valid because `next` is a **pointer** to `struct part`, so it has the size of a pointer-type.

C is a typed language, so the compiler knows the type of `next`, and after `struct part` is fully defined, it will be able to determine that the code below is valid. It knows that `next` is a pointer to `struct part`, that has a field `int a`.

```
void test(struct part *p) {
    if (p != NULL && p->next != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", p->next->a); // this is valid
    }
}
```

You could declare

```
typedef struct part 
{
   int a;
   void *next;
} Part;
```

The size of `struct part` would still be the same as the declared above. Now `next` is a pointer to anything, and the code with `test()` above would compile with error.

```
warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer
error: request for member 'a' in something not a structure or union
```

You would need to write `printf("%d\n", ((struct part *) p->next)->a);`

Also, you will not be able to declare this,

```
typedef struct part 
{
   int a;
   struct part nested;
} Part;
```

You will get a compiler error.

```
error: field 'nested' has incomplete type
```

Answer (score 1):

@MikeSeymur and others gave great answers. I want to add an important point nobody stated explicitly.

In large projects it is important to keep headers rather minimal and avoid `#include`-ing other headers unless absolutely necessary.

Assume that your structure is defined in some header file `part.h`. The named structure type `Part` defined allows other who use your code to skip **#include "part.h"** by using so called "forward-declaration":

```
//file foo.h knows struct Part "by name only"
struct Part;
void foo(struct Part* p); //in pure C, works for C++ too
void bar(Part* p); //in C++
```

In the case of anonymous structure, the file foo.h **is forced** to **#include** the file part.h

```
//file foo.h forced to #include part.h because "part" is typedef of anonymous type
#include "part.h"
void foo(part* p);
```

In legacy code quite often these anonymous types lead to a situation when every header includes so many other headers that maintenance and code reuse become a nightmare.

In general I would suggest not to use the anonymous types unless you know precisely what you are doing (there is a number of cases when they are completely OK, e.g. as implementation members of other types).